# hdashline with starting and ending markers latex

Tags: latex

Can we have use `hdashline` with starting and ending markers? Something like

<---------->

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

some text

\noindent\tikz{\draw[<->,dashed] (0,0) -- (\textwidth-0.4pt,0);}

some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you need this in a table, you can use the `nicematrix` package (inspired by this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/635224/36296 )

```
\documentclass{article}          
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       command = arrowrule ,
       tikz = { dashed, <-> }
     }
  }


\begin{NiceTabular}{XX}
  some & text\\
  \arrowrule
  some & text\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I guess I was not clear in the question. I meant within table environment.